# How to access reference on the list?

Tags: c#, list, reference

```
 Class1 : IClass
 {
     // ...
 }

 List<IClass> newList = new List<IClass>();
 Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
 newList.Add(obj1);
```

I have list of references, right? Now, the new object comes up. For example obj2 which is an instance of Class1 as well. I would like to assign obj2 to obj1 using reference available on the list(note! I can't access obj1 directly). How could I do it?

Comment: If you want your list to contain a reference to obj2 instead of obj1 you need to remove obj1 from the list and insert obj2 in its stead.

Comment: Your questing is not clear though you can assign objects or instances to each other, you only can assign variables, fields, etc. It would help if you can clarify what you mean by "assign obj2 to obj1 using reference available on the list". Without further explanation this part does not make any sense to me.

Comment: As user3076439 said.
The list contains references to objects, not values. I want to get this reference and save obj2 under the address.

Comment: Unless you do something unusual you don't have direct access to address space in C# so that talking about addresses here does not make sense. Considering GC and JIT what actual addresses are is anyone's guess. So no, you can't guarantee that addresses will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that you want `obj2` to point to the same value that `obj1` originally pointed to.  If so then just grab the value out of the list with the indexer

```
Class1 obj2 = (Class1)newList[0];
```

Note that I had to insert a cast there.  The type of elements in the list is `IClass1` but you specified `obj2` as `Class1`.

Comment: No, I want obj1 to point the same value as obj2. Obj2 has the worthy data, however I can only use obj1 via List.

Comment: You want to change obj1 then?  What does this have to do with the list?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use LINQ to find the exact object you need from the list, if for instance `obj1` wasn't the first item:

```
Class1 obj2
  = (Class1)newList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.SomeUniquePropertyOfClass1 == someId);
```

You might have to compare multiple properties in your object, but I don't know what `Class1` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

What he/she means is that you have Object1, Object2(both of the same class) and List of Objects.

List1 points to Object1 and the question is, how to make Object1 point to Object2 using reference from the list.

```
newList[0] = obj2
```

would only change the reference on the list, however obj1 would stay immutable.